# Android context is null?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service, android-context

I am making an app to remind me to take a break from work every 10 minutes (look away from computer) and every hour (take a 10 min break, which is tracked by an accelerometer).

The app uses an AlarmManager to schedule alarms. You have to press the Start button to schedule the alarms. Every 10 minutes, the ShortBreakNotif broadcast is fired. Every hour, the BreakNotifService is fired. (I've shortened these times for testing).

The ShortBreakNotif and BreakNotifService both need to start the MusicService. So, because there are two spots where the musicIntent for startService() is needed, I'm trying to make the musicIntent only in the TimerViewActivity and have it available for the TimerViewActivity onDestroy method. Is that the correct way to do this? It doesn't work (TimerViewActivity, line 251):

```
musicIntent = new Intent(TimerViewActivity.this, MusicService.class);
```

It seems like the context is null. Could that be because the activity hasn't been fully initialized? How can that be if the musicIntent is only created after several seconds? It says:
`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference`

getApplicationContext() also doesn't work. That results in this error: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference`

How should I do this?

Here's the full project: https://github.com/felixglusch/AccelTimer/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/felix/acceltimer

If you have any questions regarding the code, please ask.

Comment: I think you have to create one intent in the receiver and one in the service and don't try to encapsulate in the activity because the contexts will be different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be creating activities via a constructor. For example, in this instance, you should be using the context parameter instead of newing up a `TimerViewActivity.java` (which, you're right, won't properly get initialized).

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    Log.i("BroadCastNotif", "**** BROADCAST ****");

    Notif notification = new Notif();
    notification.notifyUser(context);

    TimerViewActivity tva = new TimerViewActivity();
    Intent musicIntent = tva.getNewMusicServiceIntent();
    context.startService(musicIntent);
}
```

You should be doing:

```
Intent musicIntent = new Intent(context, MusicService.class);
```

Comment: Thanks! That's what I had initially, but thought that it might be better to do `new Intent(context, MusicService.class)` in one spot.